What are the strongest arguments against Epistemic Permissivism?
My question is motivated by this answer to Are there objective standards proposed in the literature for estimating the likelihood of a hypothesis when empirical statistics are unavailable?, in particular this comment under said answer:

it’s more of a definitional paper rather than anything, and contrasts between the viewpoint that two people can be both rational with respect to the same evidence, or one is rational and the other not. Ultimately, from an epistemic standpoint, I lean a little more towards almost all of philosophy being judgement calls. I think of them as bets. But you can make a bet by flipping a coin or you can make a bet by gathering as much information as possible.

The paper alluded to by the comment is philpapers.org's entry on Epistemic Permissivism:

Epistemology > Epistemic Normativity > Epistemic Permissivism
Epistemic Permissivism
Edited by Elizabeth Jackson (Saint Louis University)
About this topic
Summary
Epistemic permissivism and impermissivism are about the way that bodies of evidence relate to rational attitudes. More precisely, epistemic impermissivism (or uniqueness) is the view that: necessarily, the evidence epistemically permits at most one doxastic attitude to a proposition. In contrast, epistemic permissivism is the view that: possibly, the evidence epistemically permits more than one doxastic attitude to a proposition. Suppose we’re trying to decide whether Smith committed some crime based on a particular body of evidence. According to impermissivists, if you have that body of evidence, there’s at most one rational attitude to take toward Smith’s guilt—if two people disagreed on Smith’s guilt, they’d either have different evidence or one of them would be irrational. Furthermore, a single person couldn’t rationally change their mind about Smith’s guilt without a change in their evidence. Permissivists, on the other hand, allow for rational disagreement, even when evidence is shared, and some permissivists—intrapersonal permissivists—go so far as to think that a single person could rationally change her mind about something without a change in evidence.
Key works
Defenders of impermissivism include White 2005, Greco & Hedden 2016, Dogramaci & Horowitz 2016,  Horowitz 2019, and Stapleford 2018. Defenders of permissivism include Kelly 2013, Schoenfield 2012, and Schoenfield 2018. See Podgorski 2016, Callahan 2021, Roeber 2020, Jackson 2021, and Jackson 2023 for defenses of intrapersonal permissivism.
Introductions
For overviews of the (im)permissivism debate, see Kopec & Titelbaum 2016, Jackson & Turnbull 2024, and Smith forthcoming. See Horowitz et al 2024 for a fun conversational piece. See Rosa 2018 for a helpful bibliographic overview.

If epistemic permissivism is true, then there is no single objective proper doxastic attitude that a rational agent should have in response to a given set of evidences and information. Multiple doxastic responses are permitted. For instance, epistemic permissivism would legitimize both belief and unbelief in God, as Elizabeth Jackson argues here:

Permissivism About Religious Belief
Elizabeth Jackson
Abstract
In this chapter, I argue that theistic belief is permissive belief. This is not a universal claim about persons or normative domains, but the claim that, for many common bodies of evidence, epistemic rationality is permissive about whether God exists. Marks of a permissive belief are rational disagreement over time, rational disagreement over persons, and powerful evidence on both sides. I argue that theistic belief fits all these criteria. I also show how considerations from divine hiddenness support permissivism about theism. Then, I show how these considerations support intrapersonal permissivism about theistic belief, using Peter Van Inwagen’s (1994) Quam Dialecta as a case study. Finally, I reply to objections.

What are the strongest arguments against Epistemic Permissivism?

BONUS: Originally the title of the question was "What are the strongest arguments against the view that all of philosophy is about "bets" or subjective judgment calls (i.e., Epistemic Permissivism)?". However, Conifold correctly pointed out my conceptual confusion through this comment:

"That all of philosophy is about "bets" or subjective judgment calls" is not what epistemic permissivism is, see SEP, Objective Bayesianism and Impermissive Bayesianism. Either answer to the uniqueness question is compatible with both objective and subjective stance. Objections to identifying credences with bet dispositions and objections to non-uniqueness are, accordingly, separate topics. Please clarify which you are asking for.

Thus, I have narrowed down the scope of the question to just Epistemic Permissivism. Having said that, answers that would like to add a few paragraphs to address the subjective judgment calls / bets aspect of the original title are welcome as well.

@ScottRowe - Those ways are not subject to change?? So, people didn't improve building techniques in California to make the buildings more earthquake-proof? People didn't make floating houses in Holland? Are you an actual engineer or just a software "engineer"? :)

"That all of philosophy is about "bets" or subjective judgment calls" is not what epistemic permissivism is, see SEP, Objective Bayesianism and Impermissive Bayesianism. Either answer to the uniqueness question is compatible with both objective and subjective stance. Objections to identifying credences with bet dispositions and objections to non-uniqueness are, accordingly, separate topics. Please clarify which you are asking for.

@Conifold I must admit I got the concepts mixed up due to the comment that prompted the whole question. Title edited.

Yes, just to be clear, I did not say that philosophy being judgment calls is epistemic permissivism @Conifold That was more of a comment I made after linking the paper that covers epistemic permissivism . It looks like the original question was framed differently though and is now edited

In reference to the question asked, here is a paper by Roger White that argues for a less permissive outlook by pointing out issues with permissivism: https://web.mit.edu/rog/www/papers/EP.pdf. ”Evidence that has no bearing on whether Smith is guilty is no better than no evidence at all.
But the evidence cannot support both Smith’s innocence and his guilt. Whatever is evidence for P is evidence for the falsity of not-P and hence is evidence against not-P” (This is the initial, crude version of his argument, and he spends the rest of the paper outlining it and responding to objections)

One more thing: one can have the opinion that philosophy can be represented as judgment calls or bets without adopting the notion of Bayesianism at all or choosing to model credences as subjective probabilities that correspond to bets.

A common argument for impermissivism is Aumann's agreement theorem: Bayesian agents with common priors and common knowledge of each others' evidence must have the same credences, "cannot agree to disagree", as it is loosely phrased. Aaronson argues that rationality ultimately dictates even the setting of priors. For a survey of arguments see Rosa, Uniqueness and Permissiveness in Epistemology.

I think theists would argue for their point of view and against any 'permissiveness' that other views could be correct (thus rendering themselves to be in error). If permissiveness is necessary to theism, then it is also its nemesis. Perhaps this is why the question remains 'unresolved': it defeats itself. Maybe the solution is like in the Monty Hall Problem - always change your answer when asked to?

Perhaps dwelling in one's natural attitude without philosophical Occam razor's Pyrrhonic epoche-style bracketing becomes the strongest counter or obstacle against epistemic permissivism...
